# Does something in orbit have zero spin if it always faces the object in orbit, or a distant star (fixed point)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, orbital-motion

If a satellite is in orbit around Earth, does it have 0 spin if it is always facing Earth, or if it is facing a distant star (fixed point)?  For example, if the satellite could contract, which state would it not accelerate its rotation if it contracted?  This would be a way to test which is correct as well.

Comment: Are you talking about spin, i.e. angular momentum with respect to an axis through the center of mass? An object A orbiting another object B will certainly have angular momentum about an axis through B, right?

Comment: Yes, spin is correct (around its own axis).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are talking about the 'spin' angular momentum.

This would be zero if the satellite always faced a distant star.  If such a satellite contracted then its rotation wouldn't increase.

Why it's so, is a deep question.

There was Newton's bucket.  Newton considered that rotation is relative to an absolute space.  A satellite always facing the earth has a definite or 'absolute' rotation according to Newton's view.

Experiments such as the Michelson Morley experiment failed to detect motion of the earth relative to the aether and the absolute space idea went out of fashion.

Mach disagreed with the Newtonian absolute space proposal.  One version of Mach's principle is that acceleration has to be measured relative to something and that it could be measured relative to the distant matter in the universe.

It's caused some theorists to wonder if distant  matter also causes inertia, rotational and translational, it's a topic that's still under debate today.